# UWP URI for installing a specific language/region

Tags: c#, uwp, uri, settings, windows-10-universal

I wrote a Chinese language-learning [app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/lingvoji/9pd43zx3nt8s) that uses Microsoft's Chinese speech/handwriting recognition engines. To make the installation/user experience as painless as possible, I navigate the user to the [Local Experience Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057758/windows-10-local-experience-packs) for Chinese in the Microsoft Store where they can click "Install/Get".

I use this URI scheme: (You can copy this into your browser or file explorer to test yourself on Windows 10.)

```
ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9nrmnt6gmz70
```

This is useful because it avoids the user accidentally choosing the wrong dialect or between Traditional/Simplified. Likewise, I could navigate them to the Latin American dialect of Spanish instead of Spain if they are studying Spanish. If I used the URI for the Settings -> Language & Region, users would have to search and click the correct choices manually.

[image]

After clicking "Install/Get", the user is brought to the Settings app where they will be asked to install the respective language chosen in the Store.

However, it is still a poor user experience to have the user open the Store page and install from there. For one, the page is completely written in Chinese, and the Store reviews are about 2.5 stars with people complaining about it being preinstalled on their computers. It looks more "legitimate" if users just see their own Settings page instead.

But I was thinking, clicking the Install/Get button on the store page simply brings the user to the Settings app with a view like this:

[image]

This is great because it is clear what is being done given the context of having navigated from my app; they need to install a required language with speech and handwriting recognition options.

This suggests to me that the Store is using a URI scheme to navigate directly to the Settings -> Languages screen **and pre-select a specific language**. However, there is no specific URI deep-link like this documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

**Is there an undocumented URI** that will take a user directly to the installation screen for a specific Language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an undocumented URI that will take a user directly to the installation screen for a specific Language?

For now, there's no such an URI for you to do it. Please submit a **Feature Request** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: How does the Microsoft Store app implement navigation to a language installation screen?

Comment: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/37013110-settings-uri-for-installing-a-specific-language-re